# Fixed on later Jquery Plugin for bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for a fixed on later jquery plugin and it makes the navbar appear after scrolling down the page length. However, I don't want this on all my pages. I don't really know jquery so how do I edit this to make it appear at the top of the page, no matter what?

This might make more sense: This code is designed to make the navbar appear after scrolling down the length of a page. I don't want that. I just want the navbar to appear at the top. However, if I remove this code, the navbar never appears. Is there a way to alter this code to make it appear at the top of the page, no matter what? I'm not completely familiar with jquery so it's confusing :/. Sorry for being unclear

```
(function (c) {
var a = c(window),
d = a.height();
a.resize(function () {
    d = a.height()
});
c.fn.fixedonlater = function (e) {
    function b() {
        windowScrollTop = a.scrollTop();
        g.each(function () {
            var a = c(this),
            b = a.outerHeight();
            windowScrollTop > d - b ? 0 == a.css("opacity") && a.animate({
                top : "0",
                opacity : "1"
            }, {
                queue : !1,
                duration : f.speedDown
            }) : a.animate({
                top : -b,
                opacity : "0"
            }, {
                queue : !1,
                duration : f.speedUp
            })
        })
    }
    var f = e = c.extend({
            speedDown : 250,
            speedUp : 100
        }, e),
    g = c(this);
    a.bind("scroll", b).resize(b);
    b()
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking. Can you try rewording it to make it clearer?

Comment: Yeah. This code is designed to make the navbar appear after scrolling down the length of a page. I don't want that. I just want the navbar to appear at the top. However, if I remove this code, the navbar never appears. Is there a way to alter this code to make it appear at the top of the page, no matter what? I'm not completely familiar with jquery so it's confusing :/. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me fix this...

I made a copy of the .js file and renamed it... then reference that in your page. Simply remarking out the script will never show the menu...

You basically want

```
windowScrollTop > d - b
```

to be always true. Here's my "update" function

```
function update() {
        windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        $obj.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();

            if(true){//windowScrollTop > (windowHeight - $thisHeight)) {
                if($this.css('opacity') == 0) {
                    $this.animate({
                        top: "0",
                        opacity: '1'
                    }, { 
                        queue: false,
                        duration: o.speedDown
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $this.animate({
                    top: -$thisHeight,
                    opacity: '0'
                }, { 
                    queue: false,
                    duration: o.speedUp
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Note to eveyone else...
Obvious this "hack" is completely unprofessional. Don't judge, its late, I'm knackered, and fed up with chasing through others code. If you have a problem, please write to your MP.

I'll post a revised edition in a few days.